# Is there a Cells().Formula function?

Tags: vba, excel

my script compiled fine so I assumed it was ok but couldn't find it and of course it error's out on this line, this is encapsolated in a while loop, I'm just trying to have a simple way to add a formula to a row of data, then do something similar to add it to a row of data. Is there no .Formula or do I have another error?

```
Cells(arow, acol).Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & wsData.Name & "!" & Cells(fdRow, acol).Address & ":" & Cells(ldRow, acol) & ")"
acol = acol + 1
```

Comment: disregard the .Address that was my bad

Comment: Your 'CountIf' formula needs to look similar to: =COUNTIF(B2:B11,"A")   where the firt parameter is the range and the second is the value to search for.  Not sure what you have in the 'wsData,Name' field, etc. Oh, FYI it is good practice to give the specific error code/message since there are so many possibilities.

Comment: Thanks again, all I can say is DUH...lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a few little changes needed:

1. You're missing a `.Address` on `Cells(ldRow, acol)`
2. I also included apostrophes `'` around the worksheet name (only necessary if the name has spaces in it).
3. As @Wayne G. Dunn also pointed out you need the second parameter of the `COUNTIF` function, which I have put at the end as `1`. You'll need to update that.

Here is the updated code:

```
Cells(arow, acol).Formula = "=COUNTIF('" & wsData.Name & "'!" & Cells(fdRow, acol).Address & ":" & Cells(ldRow, acol).Address & ",1)"
```

Comment: OH GREAT, thanks I had been beating my head against the key board for an hour...LOL

Comment: @RickFlyFish https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work